# How do make ImageAwesome react to hover (change foreground color) like a textblock on a button in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have found a workaround by using unicode instead of ImageAwesome but I would much rather not have to look up all of the icons' unicode of all of the font awesome icons I am using in my program.

The font awesome package I am using is: https://github.com/MartinTopfstedt/FontAwesome5

Here's a snippet of my button style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource PrimClr}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SecClr}" Opacity="0.8"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SecClr}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource PrimClr}" Opacity="0.8" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.3"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

Here's the example of how I use a button in my program:

```
            <Button x:Name="SubmitBtn" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="200" Height="45" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="SubmitBtn_Click">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <fa5:ImageAwesome Icon="Solid_UserCheck" Foreground="GhostWhite" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="Save Player"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

Please note: not putting a color for foreground results in the default black color, I at least want something to show in the mean time.

The color of the ImageAwesome does not take the styles from the button style like the textblock does... I want to be able to make it do so but I cannot find an answer anywhere! Any help would be appreciated.

Also, here's the workaround I found and I hope its not the only solution...

```
            <Button x:Name="SubmitBtn" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Width="200" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="/FontAwesome.Sharp;component/fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" Text="&#xf0c7;" FontSize="24" Margin="0,0,10,0" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="Submit" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I should have been using FontAwesome instead of ImageAwesome.

```
<Button x:Name="SubmitBtn" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="200" Height="45" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="SubmitBtn_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <fa5:FontAwesome Icon="Solid_UserCheck" FontSize="24" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Save Player"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

The only problem, and its not a big deal, in the designer it shows as a square.. so I just have to make sure I'm choosing the correct icon.